# Cases related list on Opportunity not displaying some case records

Tags: opportunity, page-layout, related-list, case-object

We have a custom lookup on Case object to the Opportunity object. On this field, the related list label is named 'Cases'. We added the related list Cases to the Opportunity page layout.

The user (even system admin) is able to view the case record. Navigate to the Opportunity record via the custom lookup - all fine. When the user looks at the related list, they see Cases [0].

This happens only for a few records and any new records that we create works properly. We even related the same Opportunity record to multiple Cases, and only the new cases we related them to showed up in the related list.

The biggest problem is, we're not able to replicate this issue (its only for some existing records) AND its surely not a sharing issue because (i) the user is able to see the case detail page (ii) this happens even for the System Admin.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there's a standard related list called 'Cases' on Opportunity. This picks up all the sibling cases (via the Account parent). That is, it picks up all Cases related to the same Account that the Opportunity is related to. We'd added the standard Cases related list instead of the custom one we created.

We had some old case records which had a different account on case than the opportunity which is why they didn't show up in the related list.

Also, we now have some logic in place which updates the Account on Case from the one in Opportunity whenever the Opportunity field is changed - this ensured both Accounts were the same and we couldn't replicate the issue!

We have now renamed our custom related list to something more appropriate to our business :)

Comment: We will have the many cases connected to many opportunities all for the same Account. This means we cannot use the standard 'Cases' related list because an Opportunity will show more than one Case in the related list which is not what we want